# The original Mutant Ninja Turtles Graphic Novels

Tags: comics, episode-identification, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

I remember when I was about 13-14 years old a friend had the original *Mutant Ninja Turtles* graphic novel. It was much much darker in content and played on the Vigilante theme a lot more.

In particular I remember a scene where the turtles catch a mugger, kill him and hang his dismembered body from a street light as a warning.

I have been trying to find these original graphic novels for several years but can't work out what they where called, the year they where published and if they are still available to buy new or are collectors items?

Comment: This is undoubtedly the 1984 comic series, or Volume 1, however, there are 62 issues in it so it'd take a while to find the specific issue you are after. The prologue of issue 1 ends with them killing a gang and a streetlight in the background, does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VboSK.jpg) look familiar? (In case you're mis-remembering them actually hanging a body).

Comment: I am pretty sure the graphic novel I read wasn't in black and white. I might be mis remembering the stringing up a gang leader. Are these 1984 comics available to buy still?

Comment: Maybe, probably from collectors. Various sites have them online but I won't link because of their dubious legal status'.

Comment: Coloured versions from IDW Turtle stores have less tugs and more foot clan soldier.